# Error when fitting experimental data containing zero with a log model

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I am trying to fit a set of experimental data with a model using NonlinearModelFit, but I receive an error message that I have been unable to fix. The error message I receive is shown below. Please help me to resolve this issue.

As I feel this equation  (v1 = Log[I1] (1 + 1/(m - 1/E1))) gives log 0 so I get an error like below. so how can I overcome it? As this is a part of the model equation I use for fitting I can't omit it. What Shall I do?

```
data1 = {{0, 0.}, {0.5, 5.39544*10^-7},
         {1, 1.42663*10^-7}, {1.5, 2.26077*10^-6},
         {2, 2.93017*10^-6}, {2.5, 3.44137*10^-6}}

T = 294.15     (* absolute temperature*)
k = 8.99 * 10^9   (* Boltzmann Constant*)
q  = 1.602 * 10^-19(*Electric Charge *)
s = N[Pi * 50^2 * 10^-18](* Area of the Nanowire  *)
m = N[q/(k*T)]

v1 = Log[I1] (1 + 1/(m - 1/E1))
v2 = I1 R1
v3 = Log[fp1]
v4 = Log[fp2]/(m - 1/E1)
v5 = m/n1
v6 = Log[1 - e^-m]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
  Abs[v1 + v2 - v3 - v4 - v5 - v6], {fp1, fp2, E1, R1, n1}, I1]
```

> NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value `{Indeterminate,-5.39544*10^-7+Abs[0.5 -1. Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]],-1.42663*10^-7+Abs[1. -1. Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]],-2.26077*10^-6+Abs[1.5 -1. Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]],-2.93017*10^-6+Abs[2. -1. Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]],-3.44137*10^-6+Abs[2.5 -1. Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]]}` is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {6} at {fp1,fp2,E1,R1,n1} = {1.,1.,1.,1.,1.}.

Comment: The issue raised has to do with your starting values.  The default starting value is 1 for each of your parameters.  You will need to provide better guesses for this type of problem to be solvable by Mathematica.

Comment: Should be `v6 = Log[1 - E^-m ]`

Comment: There are several issues:  (1) Attempting to fit 6 parameters (`fp1`, `fp2`, `E1`, `R1`, `n1`, and the error variance) to just 6 data points, (2) The model contains `Log[I1]` and one of your values of `I1` is zero, (3) The model has only 3 estimable parameters as it can be rewritten as `Abs[a - I1 R1 + b Log[I1]]` with `a = 6.058065537151313*^-32/n1 + Log[1 - 1/e^6.058065537151313*^-32] + Log[fp1] - (E1 Log[fp2])/(1 - 6.058065537151313*^-32 E1)` so even if you had more data, it would be impossible to obtain separate estimates for `n1`, `fp1`, `fp2`, and `E1`.